# Solve the partial differential equation using lagrange equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lagrange-multiplier

> $$z(x+y)p+z(x-y)q=x^2+y^2$$

I am able to solve the first part and the answer is $x^2-y^2-z^2=u
$
The next part I am not able to solve but the ans is $2xy-z^2$

Comment: This does not make any sense.

Comment: You mean the attempt or the question ? @Andrei

Comment: @Aryadeva The question. What are $p$ and $q$? And what's the first part and the next part?

Comment: Oh $p= \dfrac {dx}{dz}$ and $q=\dfrac {dy}{dz}$ @Andrei  For first part and second one I don't know what OP means by that

Answer (score 1):

For a first constant of integration we have:
$$\dfrac {dx}{x+y}=\dfrac {dy}{x-y}$$
$$\dfrac {d(x-y)}{2y}=\dfrac {dy}{x-y}$$
$$(x-y)^2=2y^2+c_1$$
$$ \implies c_1=x^2-2xy-y^2$$
For the second constant of integration:
$$\dfrac {dx}{x+y}=\dfrac {dy}{x-y}=\dfrac {zdz}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\dfrac {d(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac {2zdz}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$d(x^2-y^2)=2zdz$$
Integration gives us:
$$x^2-y^2=z^2+c_2$$
$$ \implies c_2=x^2-y^2-z^2$$
So the solution is:
$$c_2=f(c_1)$$
$$\boxed {z^2=x^2-y^2+f(x^2-2xy-y^2)}$$

Comment: Thank you the answer its correct

Comment: We can replace x^2-y^2 as z^2

Comment: Where do you want to replace it ? @ArjunShaji  Surely you can replace it...There are many formulations of the constants of integration